# Error message is popping up when running js in vscode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I just started to learn Javascript. I decided the best thing to use was vscode, as I use it for other programming projects. But when I do even a simple statement which I know is right, such as "console.log('hello world')" it gives a error message. Something along the lines of file "c:\Program Files\ Python39\lib\run.py.py" , line 197, in _run_module_as_main. I have tried making a new JavaScript file, and install additional support for js. But It did not work. code:

```
console.log('hello world')
```

Comment: Sorry about the title, I misspelled it.

Comment: you can change it yourself. Just click on "Edit" in the bottom left corner of your question. It's actually not possible for me to edit your question since the [edit queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345125/suggested-edit-queue-is-full) is full...

Comment: Are you trying to run a javascript file using python?  How are you running this file?

Comment: Please add more details and a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question. And why is it a ".py" file  instead of ".js"?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, it is a js file. How I made it: I made a new file in vscode, I pressed save as, I types in the title and put a .js, and I put down, console.log('hello world')

Answer (score 1):

I think you should start learning by using chrome or firefox console.

[Chrome Detail](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/javascript)

[Firefox Detail](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console)

Comment: İf this helped you, can you upvote my answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run JS file on VSCode you can simply go ahead and install node on your machine, and use it run js code in the terminal. Just google it how to install and then use command `node <fileName>.js` and this will do the job. And in case you don't know how to open terminal in vscode just use  command: ctrl + `

Comment: I tried that but I got this error in terminal,

Comment: At line:1 char:6
+ node <fileName>.js
+      ~
The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RedirectionNotSupported